# using comprehension in python3

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am making a python3 script and the following code is in my code:

```
Neg = [np.mean(np.log2(np.array(i['Negative'],np.float64))+2*np.std(np.log2(np.array(i['Negative'],np.float64)) for i in Dis]
```

but when I run the script I will get this error:

```
  File "QC.py", line 104
    Neg = [np.mean(np.log2(np.array(i['Negative'],np.float64))+2*np.std(np.log2(np.array(i['Negative'],np.float64)) for i in Dis] 
                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I did not get what the problem is. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't write a question title using the word "solved".

Answer (score 0):

you forgot some closing parenthesis

```
Neg = [np.mean(np.log2(np.array(i['Negative'],np.float64))+2*np.std(np.log2(np.array(i['Negative'],np.float64)))) for i in Dis]
```

try this